# Jquery click function not working on IE 11

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#skip').click(function () {
            $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
        });

});
</script>



<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ><u id="skip">skip</u></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution:
when I change the id skip from underline tag to button tag like below
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="skip" ><u >skip</u></button>`
it works ! I am trying to understand why the change in id position is working?

Any help ! much appreciated.

Comment: can you setup fiddle

Comment: This is because click event by default is for Button and you are wrapping <u> inside button, so by default click even will work for button not <u>. so `jQuery('#skip').click(function () ` will work of button with id="skip"` is there

Comment: looks ok to me set up a fiddle fo shizzle dizzle

Comment: @Learning, Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Learning : In chrome , irrespective of the position of Id , the code is working fine.Why is that?

Comment: Im assuming you're using bootstrap so why not use the bootstrap built in function like this:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">SKIP</button>`

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('hide'); => $('#exampleModal').hide();
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mz9os3ep/2/